# grunt task src filtering from cli

Tags: node.js, testing, filter, gruntjs, meanjs

I have a grunt task that runs all of my nodejs server side test files.

```
grunt.registerTask('serverTest', ['env:test', 'mongoose', 'mochaTest']);
```

While developing tests I would like to only run the test I'm currently working on. My task is setup to run a list of all test assets in the code base:

```
mochaTest: {
        src: testAssets.tests.server,
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec'
        }
    },
```

I would like to specify a filter parameter at the cli to only select a specific file from `testAssets.tests.server` which is a big list of tests since it's defined as `modules/*/tests/server/**/*.js` and returns every test in the code base.

For example if I entered the following at the command line:

```
grunt serverTest:*fileUnderTest.js
```

Grunt would filter the `testAssets.tests.server` and only execute the files that match `*fileUnderTest.js`

I've read through the documentation and seen a lot of examples but can't figure out how to do this without creating a separate target and specifying the file name in the grunt file.

Comment: You could probably do this using Grunt options and creating a custom parameter to pass a custom globbing pattern in from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Grunt options, it was exactly what I needed. See one potential solution below.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient means but the following code at the start of my gruntfile got the filtering working for me.

```
// get regex epression from CLI
var expression = grunt.option('filter');

//filter the testAssets.tests.server array
var testFiles = filtered(getGlobbedPaths(testAssets.tests.server),expression);

// test array with regex and return array of matches
var filtered = (function(arr,pattern){
    var filtered = [],
        i = arr.length,
        re = new RegExp(pattern);

    while (i--) {
        if (re.test(arr[i])) {
            filtered.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
});
```

And then the grunt task becomes:

```
mochaTest: {
        src: testFiles,
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec'
        }
    }
grunt.registerTask('serverTest', ['env:test', 'mongoose', 'mochaTest']);
```

So a command line call such as:

```
grunt serverTest --filter=comment.server.model.tests.js
```

Will run any test file matching the filter and a command like:

```
grunt serverTest
```

Will run all test files in the project

For reference my project is based on meanjs which globs all the paths to files so I run the `getGlobbedPaths()` function which is defined in config.js to first expand the file path array prior to filtering:

```
var getGlobbedPaths = function(globPatterns, excludes) {
// URL paths regex
var urlRegex = new RegExp('^(?:[a-z]+:)?\/\/', 'i');

// The output array
var output = [];

// If glob pattern is array so we use each pattern in a recursive way, otherwise we use glob
if (_.isArray(globPatterns)) {
    globPatterns.forEach(function(globPattern) {
        output = _.union(output, getGlobbedPaths(globPattern, excludes));
    });
} else if (_.isString(globPatterns)) {
    if (urlRegex.test(globPatterns)) {
        output.push(globPatterns);
    } else {
        glob(globPatterns, {
            sync: true
        }, function(err, files) {
            if (excludes) {
                files = files.map(function(file) {
                    if (_.isArray(excludes)) {
                        for (var i in excludes) {
                            file = file.replace(excludes[i], '');
                        }
                    } else {
                        file = file.replace(excludes, '');
                    }

                    return file;
                });
            }

            output = _.union(output, files);
        });
    }
}

return output;
};
```